# How to set Line item number for each group

Tags: xslt-1.0

Can someone please help me out with this scenario asap?

**Input XML:**

```
<dataXML>
<Items>
    <itemLine>
        <lineNo>1</lineNo>
        <lineRefNo>001</lineRefNo>
        <lineDes>test1</lineDes>
    </itemLine>
    <itemLine>
        <lineNo>2</lineNo>
        <lineRefNo>001</lineRefNo>
        <lineDes>test2</lineDes>
    </itemLine>
    <itemLine>
        <lineNo>3</lineNo>
        <lineRefNo>002</lineRefNo>
        <lineDes>test3</lineDes>
    </itemLine>
    <itemLine>
        <lineNo>4</lineNo>
        <lineRefNo>002</lineRefNo>
        <lineDes>test4</lineDes>
    </itemLine>
    <itemLine>
        <lineNo>5</lineNo>
        <lineRefNo>002</lineRefNo>
        <lineDes>test5</lineDes>
    </itemLine>
    <itemLine>
        <lineNo>6</lineNo>
        <lineRefNo>003</lineRefNo>
        <lineDes>test6</lineDes>
    </itemLine>
</Items>
```

I have regrouped item lines based on LineRefNo

**Transformation xsl:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="totalLine" select="count(dataXML/Items/itemLine)" />

<Root>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;','test','&gt;')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="dataXML/Items/itemLine">
        <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="lineRefNo != preceding-sibling::itemLine[1]/lineRefNo">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;/','test','&gt;')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;','test','&gt;')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
            <item>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat('Line No : ',position())" />,<xsl:value-of select="lineRefNo" />
            </item>
            <xsl:if test="$totalLine = position()">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;/','test','&gt;')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <item>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat('Line No : ',position())" />,<xsl:value-of select="lineRefNo" />
            </item>
            <xsl:if test="$totalLine = position()">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;/','test','&gt;')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
</Root>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Note :** Please escape '>' and '<' in xslt transformation where Test and Item tags are used

It will transform input xml as below result

```
 **Result :**
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
    <test>
        <item>Line No : 1,001</item>
        <item>Line No : 2,001</item>
    </test>
    <test>
        <item>Line No : 3,002</item>
        <item>Line No : 4,002</item>
        <item>Line No : 5,002</item>
    </test>
    <test>
        <item>Line No : 6,003</item>
    </test>
</Root>

**Expected Result:**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
    <test>
        <item>Line No : 1,001</item>
        <item>Line No : 2,001</item>
    </test>
    <test>
        <item>Line No : 1,002</item>
        <item>Line No : 2,002</item>
        <item>Line No : 3,002</item>
    </test>
    <test>
        <item>Line No : 1,003</item>
    </test>
</Root>
```

Thanking in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kItemsByRef" match="itemLine"
  use="lineRefNo"/>

 <xsl:template match=
  "itemLine
     [generate-id()
     =
      generate-id(key('kItemsByRef', lineRefNo)[1])
     ]
  ">
  <test>
   <xsl:for-each select="key('kItemsByRef', lineRefNo)">
     <item>Line No : <xsl:value-of select=
      "concat(position(), ',', lineRefNo)"/>
      </item>
   </xsl:for-each>
  </test>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<dataXML>
    <Items>
        <itemLine>
            <lineNo>1</lineNo>
            <lineRefNo>001</lineRefNo>
            <lineDes>test1</lineDes>
        </itemLine>
        <itemLine>
            <lineNo>2</lineNo>
            <lineRefNo>001</lineRefNo>
            <lineDes>test2</lineDes>
        </itemLine>
        <itemLine>
            <lineNo>3</lineNo>
            <lineRefNo>002</lineRefNo>
            <lineDes>test3</lineDes>
        </itemLine>
        <itemLine>
            <lineNo>4</lineNo>
            <lineRefNo>002</lineRefNo>
            <lineDes>test4</lineDes>
        </itemLine>
        <itemLine>
            <lineNo>5</lineNo>
            <lineRefNo>002</lineRefNo>
            <lineDes>test5</lineDes>
        </itemLine>
        <itemLine>
            <lineNo>6</lineNo>
            <lineRefNo>003</lineRefNo>
            <lineDes>test6</lineDes>
        </itemLine>
    </Items>
</dataXML>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<test>
   <item>Line No : 1,001</item>
   <item>Line No : 2,001</item>
</test>
<test>
   <item>Line No : 1,002</item>
   <item>Line No : 2,002</item>
   <item>Line No : 3,002</item>
</test>
<test>
   <item>Line No : 1,003</item>
</test>
```

Comment: Hi, what to do if i want to add Root node for all "test" node? Could u help me, I have tried but not able to set root node.

Comment: @DVekaria: Add this template: `<xsl:template match="/"><top><xsl:apply-templates/></top></xsl:template>`

Comment: Could you please check below link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546085/how-to-find-index-position-for-group-line-item-in-xsl